# Get sublist of dictionaries based on attribute condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this list of dictionaries:

```yaml
some_list:
  - name: alfa
    dir: aaa
  - name: beta
    dir: bbb
  - name: gamma
    dir: ggg
```

and I want to get, via Ansible/Jinja, a subset of `some_list`, should still be a list, which only contains the dicts having `name in ['alfa', 'beta']`.

I will use the sublist in a `with_items`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) filter along with the [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.in) test for that.

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: some_list | selectattr('name', 'in', ['alfa', 'beta'])
```

This would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  some_list | selectattr('name', 'in', ['alfa', 'beta']):
  - dir: aaa
    name: alfa
  - dir: bbb
    name: beta
```

Comment: Thanks! worked great. I added an extra `| list` at the end